# Communicate with C# host from edge.js

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, edge.js

I'm trying to put together a quick node.js/edge.js/C# bridge for a demo.

I have to use the [".Net calling Node.js"](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge#how-to-integrate-nodejs-code-into-clr-code) style, as the existing C# code uses a number of config values, which I can't add to node.exe.config as I will need to run several versions concurrently.

So I have this code:

```
private static async Task Start() {

    Func<object, Task<object>> edge = EdgeJs.Edge.Func(@"

        var login = require('login.js');
        var edge = require('edge')

        login({ email: 'user@example.com', password: 'shh' }, function callback(err, api) {

            if (err) return console.error(err);

            // This will keep listening until terminated
            api.listen(function callback(err, message) {
                if (err) return console.error(err);

                // At this point I need to send the message back to this class so it can be processed..
                console.log(message); // send the message to C#

                // ... and then return the response via the api
                api.send('response goes here');      
            });
        });

        return function (data, callback) {
            callback(null, er...);
        }               
    ");    

}
```

So, the code is waiting for messages in an event loop and responding. This all works with hardcoded values. But I need to submit the message back to the C# for processing, and I cannot work out how to communicate back and forth between edge.js and the C# app.

It must surely be via the callback, but I can't seem to start figure out how to structure it, and time is getting short. And I'm by no means a JavaScript expert.

How can I communicate between the edge code and the C# code from within the event loop using the callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ended up with something like this: there's a function defined on the data passed to edge, which edge then calls when a new message is received. That function then waits for the response, and passes it back to edge, which receives the result in (of course) another callback.

```
private static async Task Start() {
    dynamic payload = new ExpandoObject();
    payload.msgHook = NewMessage;
    payload.login = new {
        email,
        password
    };

    var receive = Edge.Func(@"    

            return function(payload, edge_callback) {

                var login = require('index.js');

                login({
                    email: payload.login.email,
                    password: payload.login.password
                }, function callback(err, api) {

                    if (err) {
                        edge_callback(err); 
                    }

                    api.listen(function callback(err, message) {
                        if (err) { edge_callback(err); }

                        payload.msgHook(message,
                            function callback(err, result) {
                                if (err) {
                                    edge_callback(err);
                                }


                                var msg = {
                                        body: result.body,
                                        url: result.url
                                    }

                                api.sendMessage(msg, result.threadId);
                            });                   
                        });
                    });
                }    
        ");

    var _ = await receive(payload) as IDictionary<string, object>;
}

private static Func<object, Task<object>> NewMessage {
    get {
        Func<object, Task<object>> hook = async m => {
                string body, threadId;

                if (!ProcessMessage(m as IDictionary<string, object>, out body, out threadId)) {
                    log.Error("Failed to process message: " + m.ToString());
                }

                api.SendMessage(body, threadId, phone);
                var reply = await waitForReply(threadId);

            var result = new {
                body = reply
            };

            // Return the _result_ of the task.
            return Task.FromResult<object>(result).Result;
        };

        return hook;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're right, it's via the callback. Since you're using async code, you have to wrap all your code inside the returned (edge) function, like this:

```
private static async Task Start() {
    Func<object, Task<object>> edge = EdgeJs.Edge.Func(@"
        // edge_callback is used to return values to the C# code
        return function(data, edge_callback) {
          var login = require('login.js');
          var edge = require('edge')

          login({
            email: 'user@example.com',
            password: 'shh'
          }, function callback(err, api) {

            if (err) return console.error(err);
            // possible enhancement here by letting C# know there is an error
            // edge_callback(err);

            // This will keep listening until terminated
            api.listen(function callback(err, message) {
              if (err) return console.error(err);
              // same thing here: edge_callback(err);

              // At this point I need to send the message back to this class so it can be processed..
              console.log(message); // send the message to C#
              // use the callback, first param is error if there is any, second is the data
              edge_callback(null, message);

              // ... and then return the response via the api
              api.send('response goes here');
            });
          });
        }    
    ");    
}
```

Comment: This was very helpful thank you: unfortunately edge did not like being invoked multiple times (calling the edge callback terminates the edge session) so I've had to build on it.